# NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName:object:queue:using:) documentation about the object returned

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, nsobjectprotocol

What is exactly created in this function?

I'm trying to create a reusable extension so that every `UIViewController` can hold a reference to the `NSObjectProtocol` observer that's returned in this function. The `observer` doesn't seem to be the object that called the function.

so where is it created?

Comment: Read the discussion in the reference documentation for that method. The return value is only needed to call `removeObserver`.

Comment: Yes, but what is the observer? Is there a good way to store this somewhere until I'm ready to reference it again? I'm trying to make the flow reusable for different view controllers

Comment: For this specific `addObserver` method, the "observer" is the owner of the closure passed to the `using` parameter.